# Loop through Word document, starting from beginning of file at start of each loop

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looping through a Word Document in VBA.  Through each pass I'd like to search for a different word, so each pass needs to start at the beginning of the file.  The current method I'm using is this, but it appears to search for the first word, and when it gets to the end of the file, moves to the second word, and searches only at the end of the file and so on with the rest of the words.

```
'my array of words is called myKeywords
For x = LBound(myKeywords) To UBound(myKeywords)
    PageNumbers(x) = ""
    'start from start of file here somehow.
    With oWord.Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting()
        .Text = myKeywords(x)
        .Wrap = False
        .Forward = True
        Do While .Execute = True
            If PageNumbers(x) = "" Then
                PageNumbers(x) = oWord.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
            Else
                PageNumbers(x) = PageNumbers(x) & ", " & oWord.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
            End If
        Loop
    End With
Next
```

Any insight is appreciated.

**Edit 1**

I have read through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192204%28v=office.15%29.aspx), and I don't see anything that could help me.  Wrap looks like it would help, but if I set wrap = True, I get the error "Value out of range", and I don't see how .wrap could set anything out of range.

**Edit 2**

I tried setting a range and resetting it at the end of the loop, but no success so far.

```
'my array of words is called myKeywords
Range = oWord.Selection
For x = LBound(myKeywords) To UBound(myKeywords)
    PageNumbers(x) = ""
    'start from start of file here somehow.
    With Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting()
        .Text = myKeywords(x)
        .Wrap = False
        .Forward = True
        Do While .Execute = True
            If PageNumbers(x) = "" Then
                PageNumbers(x) = oWord.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
            Else
                PageNumbers(x) = PageNumbers(x) & ", " & oWord.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
            End If
        Loop
        'I've also tried several other variations of Range = other things to get this to work.
        Range = Range.Select

    End With
Next
```

**Edit 3**

```
'my array of words is called myKeywords
Range = oWord.ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=oWord.Selection.Start, [End]:=oWord.Selection.End)
For x = LBound(myKeywords) To UBound(myKeywords)

    'start from start of file here somehow.
    With oWord.Selection.Find
        PageNumbers(x) = ""
        .ClearFormatting()
        .Text = myKeywords(x)
        .Wrap = False
        .Forward = True
        Do While .Execute = True
            If PageNumbers(x) = "" Then
                PageNumbers(x) = oWord.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
            Else
                PageNumbers(x) = PageNumbers(x) & ", " & oWord.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
            End If
        Loop
        Range.Select()

    End With
Next
```

Comment: What do you achieve to do? Can't you use Find and Replace method? I can give you a sample if it would help.

Comment: Not a find and replace.  I'm trying to give this program an array of words, and if that word exists in the document, it writes to another document how many times, and what page the word is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply the `Find` to the current selection. But the selection moves by calling the `Execute` on the `Find` object. The consequence is that after the first run of the loop the selection is on the last occurence of the first verb. This will be the starting point for the next `Find.Execute`. One possible solution is to store the current selection at the start of the loop in a `Range` variable (`range=oWord.Selection`) and set the selection back to this stored range at the end of the loop (`range.Select`). (For sure there are more elegant solutions for your general problem but it could be a solution to your concrete problem.)

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I think this is the method I'd like to try and use.  I added Edit 2 to show how I tried to implement what you mentioned. I've looked up a few ways to do this, and haven't had any success.  Even after I set Range.Select at the end of the loop, after the first keyword the program is still starting at the end of the document.  Any ideas?

Comment: Edit 3 will be the working code based on what you suggested.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with VBA so I can't give exact code, but you'll be able to implement the following strategy:
If you are searching for individual words, you can just collect words one word at a time (or build them with one letter at a time, delimited by spaces and punctuation), and compare that word to a list of the keywords you want to find.
So, rather than looping through the document many times and going through your list once, you can instead go through the document once while looping through your list many times.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm using a RegExp method because it's really fast, so before I've really looped through the file once, I'll have a complete array of words I'm trying to find.  Also, because the Find method takes in a .Text field (which I set to the array) I'm not sure if there's another way besides that to cycle through and find individual words without hugely losing efficiency.  I'm not saying your idea won't work, but what I'm doing (according to what I think, and have read) is pretty efficient, so I don't want to change it much.  Not sure if I can search for all words in one pass.

Answer (score 0):

To go to the beginning of a Word document with vba, you can use:

```
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
```

Then you have to do it at the start of the loop. I found this simply by using Word's macro recorder.